# Equivalent formulations of Runge Kutta Methods?

Tags: numerical-methods

I have given two formulations of a general Runge Kutta Method with $s$ stages

1. $$ y(x+h) = y_0 + h\sum_{i=1}^{s}b_ik_i$$
   $$ k_i = f\left(x_0+c_ih;\,y_0+h\sum_{i=1}^{s}a_{ij}k_j\right)$$
2. $$ y(x+h) = y_0 + h\sum_{i=1}^{s}b_if\left(x_0+c_ih;\,y_i\right) $$
   $$ y_i = y_0 + \sum_{i=1}^{s}a_{ij}f\left(x_o+c_ih;\, y_i\right)$$

Those forumalas produce the same approximation, do they? But how can one show this?

Just putting in the definition of $k_i$ or respectivly $y_i$ leads to an "endless cycle".

Answer (score 0):

Set $y(x+h)$ from the first definition equal to $y(x+h)$ from the second, and show that they result in the same thing (which they should, because the definitions are the same).

Comment: I tried this approach, but I end up with $\sum_{i=1}^{s}k_i = \sum_{i=1}^{s}f\left(x_0+c_ih;\,y_i\right)$ and do not know how to show this equality.

Comment: @OschBert Well, use the definitions of $k_i$ and $y_i$. So, $$\sum k_i = \sum f\left(x_0+c_ih; y_0 + h\sum a_{ij}k_j\right) = \sum f(x_0+c_ih; y_i)$$ and so on.

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not see the second equality.

Comment: So, if $y_i = y_0 +h\sum_{i=1}^{s}a_{ij}k_j$ then $k_i = f\left(x_0+c_ih;\,y_i\right)$ and the result follows. Or vice versa if $k_i = f\left(x_0+c_ih;\,y_i\right)$ then $y_i = y_0 +h\sum_{i=1}^{s}a_{ij}k_j$ and the result follows. But I go round in circles, don't I?!

Comment: Start stepwise. Note that you have an error in your definition of $k_i$. It should read:

$$k_i = f\left(x_0 + c_ih; y_0 + h \color{red}{\sum_{j=1}^i} a_{ij}k_j\right).$$

Comment: Unless you're looking at an implicit RK formula, in which case the upper bound can be $s$. But even still you can still look at it stepwise.

Comment: It is a general RK method (so the upper bound s should be correct). But now I end up at the point where i have to show that $y_i = y_0+h\sum a_{ij}k_j$. This equality holds if $k_j=f\left(x_0+c_ih;\,y_i\right)$ but this equality holds if $y_i = y_0+h\sum a_{ij}k_j$ and so on...

Comment: @OschBert In the explicit case, you can start from $i=1$ and build up. In the implicit case, you get $y_i = y_0+h\sum a_{ij}k_j = y_0+h\sum a_{ij} f(x_0+c_ih; y_j)$. There is no circular reasoning. You end up with an implicit equation. This is why it's called an implicit method.

Comment: I got my error in reasoning. The trick is to set $y_i = y_0 + h\sum a_{ij}k_j$ and derive the second formulation from the first one. TY for your assistance.